# how to update the table where results are coming from select statement

Tags: oracle

How to update GT_ADD_ISBNS table if CATEGORY_EXISTS=0 then error_mesage='category not found' , if FINAL_DOCUMENTS is not null then 
finalename=FINAL_DOCUMENTS, and FINAL_DOCUMENTS is null then error_mesage='documents not found' ;

```
SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM 
        TEMP_NODE_PROPERTIES ANP,
    TEMP_NODE_PROPERTIES ANPP,
        TEMP_NODE AN
        WHERE 
      ANP.NODE_ID=AN.ID AND
    ANPP.NODE_ID=ANP.NODE_ID AND
    AN.TYPE_QNAME='asset' AND
    ANP.STRING_VALUE ='uPDF' AND ANPP.STRING_VALUE ='Entire PDF'  AND
    ANP.TYPE_QNAME='categories'  AND
        ANP.NODE_ID IN(SELECT CHILD_ID 
                  FROM TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC START WITH PARENT_ID IN(
                 SELECT CHILD_ID FROM TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC WHERE NAME in(GT.ISBN)) 
                      CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_ID = PARENT_ID)
    )  CATEGORY_EXISTS,
    (SELECT LISTAGG(T1.STRING_VALUE, ',') WITHIN GROUP  (ORDER BY T1.STRING_VALUE)
       FROM         TEMP_NODE_PROPERTIES T1
        WHERE   T1.TYPE_QNAME='name'  AND  (T1.STRING_VALUE LIKE '%pdf%'  AND  T1.STRING_VALUE NOT LIKE '%pod%') 
         AND  T1.NODE_ID IN (SELECT ANP.NODE_ID
        FROM 
        TEMP_NODE_PROPERTIES ANP,
    TEMP_NODE_PROPERTIES ANPP,
        TEMP_NODE AN
        WHERE 
      ANP.NODE_ID=AN.ID AND
    ANPP.NODE_ID=ANP.NODE_ID AND
    AN.TYPE_QNAME='asset' AND
    ANP.STRING_VALUE ='uPDF' AND ANPP.STRING_VALUE ='Entire PDF' AND
    ANP.TYPE_QNAME='categories'  AND
        ANP.NODE_ID IN(SELECT CHILD_ID 
                  FROM TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC START WITH PARENT_ID IN(
                 SELECT CHILD_ID FROM TEMP_CHILD_ASSOC WHERE NAME in(GT.ISBN)) 
                      CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_ID = PARENT_ID)))
     FINAL_DOCUMENTS
        FROM  GT_ADD_ISBNS GT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
UPDATE gt_add_isbns
   SET (error_message, filename) =
          (SELECT CASE
                     WHEN category_exists = 0 THEN 'category not found'
                     WHEN final_documents IS NULL THEN 'documents not found'
                  END,
                  CASE
                     WHEN final_documents IS NOT NULL THEN final_documents
                  END
             FROM (SELECT category_exists, final_documents
                     FROM (your current query goes here)));
```

Comment: i am getting Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
 
  WHEN I PUT existing query in the current query box that you mentioned above

Comment: It means that you'll have to restrict it, somehow. Either make sure that your query returns only 1 row, or add some more column which would then be used in the `WHERE` clause in order to avoid TOO-MANY-ROWS.